# Plot data frame's lists in ggplot2

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, data.table

I have a data.table / data frame with lists as values. I would like to make a box or violin plot of the values, one violin/box representing one row of my data set, but I can't figure out how.

Example:

```
test.dt <- data.table(id = c('a','b','c'), v1 = list(c(1,0,10),1:5,3))
ggplot(data = test.dt, aes(x = as.factor(id), y = v1)) + geom_boxplot()
```

I get the following message:

> Warning message:
>   Computation failed in `stat_boxplot()`:
>   'x' must be atomic

So my guess is that maybe I should split the lists of the values to rows somehow. I.e.: the row with **a** as **id** would be transformed to 3 rows (corresponding to the length of the vector in **v1**) with the same id, but the values would be split among them.

Firstly I don't know how to transform the data.table as mentioned, secondly I don't know either if this would be the solution at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the very handy `unnest()` function. The following code works:

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)

test.dt <- data.table(id = c('a','b','c'), v1 = list(c(1,0,10),1:5,3))
test.dt = test.dt %>% unnest()

ggplot(test.dt, aes(x = as.factor(id), y = v1)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

If you don't want to import the whole tidyverse, the `unnest()` function is from the **tidyr** package.

This is what `unnest()` does with example data:

```
> data.table(id = c('a','b','c'), v1 = list(c(1,0,10),1:5,3))
   id        v1
1:  a   1, 0,10
2:  b 1,2,3,4,5
3:  c         3
> data.table(id = c('a','b','c'), v1 = list(c(1,0,10),1:5,3)) %>% unnest()
   id v1
1:  a  1
2:  a  0
3:  a 10
4:  b  1
5:  b  2
6:  b  3
7:  b  4
8:  b  5
9:  c  3
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you need to `unnest` your dataset before plotting:

```
library(tidyverse)

unnest(test.dt) %>% 
ggplot(data = ., aes(x = as.factor(id), y = v1)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: You can also put everything in a `dplyr` chain.

Comment: The explanation was simpler in separate steps. But indeed, it's more elegant: `unnest(test.dt) %>% ggplot(data = ., aes(x = as.factor(id), y = v1)) + geom_boxplot()`

Comment: @Luminita Edited my question, thanks for pointing it out. I was trying to make a boxplot, indeed!

Comment: In case the aim is a histogram of v1 (a histogram is a univariate tool as it plots the frequency of a variable): `ggplot(data = test.dt, aes(x = v1)) + geom_histogram()`. Otherwise, one may be interested in histograms by groups (here, `id`s) - which can be achieved with `facetting`: `ggplot(data = test.dt, aes(x = v1)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~id)`